# Is it possible to host an iframe in one domain and target it to a different domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, iframe

I have a web application which tries to make a http request using jQuery to another API in a different domain which I don't have the control. That API does not return Origin in the response header so the browser prevents from sending response to the application with an error "Origin not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header". So I am trying to implement an iFrame through which the web application can send a message to API.

Is it possible to have (host) the iFrame in my web application domain and target it to the API domain? Or do I have to ask the third party API to host the iFrame in their domain? Is there any way at all to do it without dealing with the third party?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: i belive you need to configure crossdomain, to comunicate js

Comment: No, it's not possible.